# Newtons cradle physics violates relativity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, inertial-frames

I recently read an article that disputes relativity using Newton's cradle. It basically says that if you have one ball coming at velecity V with the kinetic energy of one ball, it cannot modeled as the other four balls moving the other way at -V, because then the initial kinetic energy is that of four balls moving, which is four times that of one ball is moving at the same velocity.  After all one ball moves from the other end and thus the energy is that of one ball not four.

Does this disprove relativity as the gentleman says.
https://magneticuniverse.com/discussion/359/newtons-cradle-and-electromagnetism

Comment: The header in your site has a link to 'perpetual motion holder' which links to an article that has a proposed perpetual motion machine. Anyone that claims to have found a perpetual motion machine or is actively looking for one should be approached with a healthy amount of skepticism. Just based on that article I advise you to not look at the site. It is filled with misinformation and pseudo-science.

Comment: yeah, after going to the main page,,, if you think about it, all he does is create a magnet... not perpetual motion.   he still has to add energy to get energy

Answer (score 3):

No.  Kinetic energy is not a relativistic invariant, meaning that observers in different reference frames will not agree on its value.  This is obvious - in my rest frame, the cup I'm holding has zero kinetic energy, but to somebody moving with respect to me, the cup has non-zero kinetic energy.

Comment: Absolutely, but what are your thoughts on the arguments presented in paper OP is referring to https://www.gsjournal.net/Science-Journals/Essays-Mechanics%20/%20Electrodynamics/Download/5737?

Comment: @user256872 The formatting plus the fact that the author has a hotmail email address leads me to immediately suspect that the journal is predatory and that the content is nonsense.  This is supported by the fact that in the first paragraph, the author demonstrates a complete ignorance of elasticity (e.g. [Young's modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus), which determines the response to compressive stress) which he then wields as evidence against perhaps the most well-supported theory in all of physics. The second paragraph contains a logical non-sequitur rendering it [...]

Comment: [...] similarly exasperating.  In sum, I have no interest in reading the remainder of the paper, and would label its contents as not worth consideration.

Comment: Hmm yes, it's what I suspected. Thank you for going over it and confirming.

Comment: Thanks, but i need some clarification, please.   if i look at it from the falling ball perspective, i have 4 balls coming at me... they should plow on through me, no?  But from my frame, they are instantly brought to rest, as is " the whole world".   The change in energy from that perspective is huge, yet i know its only 1 ball.

Comment: @RichEngle The frame attached to the falling ball is non-inertial, so there’s no reason to expect observations made in that frame to be equivalent to observations made in the (inertial) lab frame. Those two perspectives are not equivalent, because one is accelerating.

Comment: Thanks J, but then, how can i make conservation of energy for that ball's reference frame?   It started with 4 balls coming at me[ the one ball].   I somehow stop 4 balls???  then the world stops too [ did i do that?]

Comment: @RichEngle Why should energy be conserved in a non-inertial reference frame?

Comment: maybe i can rephrase it, what force stops the world from moving?

Comment: @RichEngle There is no force which “stops the world from moving”. You’re in a non-inertial frame, so Newton’s 1st law is out the window!

Comment: so i have to view it from a non accelerating frame?   ... like if i were standing still, say, 10 feet from the cradle?

Comment: @RichEngle Or a frame moving with constant velocity relative to that one, yes.

Comment: @J. Murray How is having a hotmail email address relevant?

Comment: @D.Halsey I was being a bit tongue-in-cheek there. Having a hotmail address is irrelevant - *listing it* on a published manuscript suggests that the author has no affiliation with an academic or industry institution, and doing so on a paper which claims to disprove one of the cornerstones of 20th century physics suggests that the author is an amateur promoting a personal theory. Not in itself disqualifying, which is why I read the first paragraph before tossing it in the metaphorical bin.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies in determining which are the inertial frames.
Before the collision, we have a system of one ball with mass m and velocity +v (relative to the other system)
and a system with 4 balls with mass 4m and velocity -v relative to the first system.
The balls can be considered to be at rest in their respective inertial systems,
although they have velocity and hence momentum relative to the other system.
Then, the balls collide. After the collision,
we have a system with one ball with mass m and relative velocity +v.
and a system with 4 balls with mass 4m and relative velocity -v.
The two systems are essentially the same before and after collision.
The two systems each maintain uniform relative velocity and conserve mass and momentum.
Of course, two of the balls switched systems during the collision.
The single ball's inertia didn't "stop" the world; it effectively just passed through it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).